# Getting certain data in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

So, I have this website that I want to send a get request and get certain data.

I was wondering how I would target this element and get the href, but only get the numbers in userAssetOptionId=1910058. The numbers will change every time I load the page but the 'userAssetOptionId' will not.

I'm thinkning I will have to do something with a substring?

```
<a data-rel="dialog" data-role="button" data-theme="d" href="/Catalog/VerifyTransfer?userAssetOptionId=1910058&amp;expectedPrice=12000" data-corners="true" data-shadow="true" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="span" class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-btn-corner-all ui-btn-hover-d ui-btn-up-d"></a>
```

Comment: will this a have an id or will it be the only a on the page?

Comment: It doesn't have an ID, and there are others and its not the only a on the page.

Comment: and yes, you'll need to do something with a substring https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is nothing unique about that anchor besides the href you could get the id this way:

```
$('a').each(function(){
    var href=$(this).attr('href');
    var id;
    var index=href.indexOf('userAssetOptionId');
    if(index>0)
        id=href.substring(index+18,href.indexOf('&'));
    alert(id);
});
```

--EDIT--

To be more precise use:

```
var href=$('a[href*="userAssetOptionId"]').attr('href');
var id=href.substring(href.indexOf('userAssetOptionId')+18,href.indexOf('&'));
```

Comment: Thanks, I ended up finding out the answer.